# ROS fuerte installation problem on 12.04

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello!

I use VMware to load Mint13 (same as Ubuntu 12.04) and then follow the installation steps on the "Ubuntu install of Fuerte" page.

But when it comes to "sudo apt-get install ros-fuerte-desktop-full" I get an error message

Reading package lists... Done

Building dependency tree

Reading state information... Done

E: Unable to locate package ros-fuerte-desktop-full

I have tried several times but it is still unable to locate package.

How can I overcome this problem and install the ROS? Thanks you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/50476/ros-fuerte-installation-problem-on-12.04/) by [clarklichli](https://answers.ros.org/users/3789/clarklichli/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2012-12-14

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ed Venator](https://answers.ros.org/users/2636/ed-venator/) on 2012-12-14**:
I'm having the same problem today on Ubuntu 12.04.1. Sources list is correct and most ROS fuerte packages appear when I try tab complete of apt-get install ros-fuerte-
I have tried both packages.ros.org and the CWRU mirror. Perhaps something is broken in the deb build for desktop-full today?

**Comment by [madmax](https://answers.ros.org/users/1492/madmax/) on 2012-12-14**:
Same problem with me too on xubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There was a sytax error in the fuerte.rosdistro file which crashed the variant metapackage generation.  The error was fixed last night and the script was made robust to the error as well.  This should be fixed now.  Make sure to apt-get update.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2012-12-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Did you execute steps 1.1 to 1.4? Mint is experimental, you can better install ubuntu or just take the pre compiled virtualbox image.

---

Originally posted by [davinci](https://answers.ros.org/users/3014/davinci/) with karma: 2573 on 2012-12-14

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2